# How can I copy Logi Options application settings from one device to another device?

Tags: macos

This should do a very simple and intuitive thing to do, but could not find how to do it in Logi Options or searching the internet.

I have all application settings in my older mouse.
Now I want to copy all those settings to my new mouse.

How can this be done?

When you do a backup it will copy the settings from each device, but when you restore, it will set to the same device. There's no way to choose which settings to set to which device.

Comment: Try More > Backups. You'll need to be signed in. idk whether this permits transfer between different devices - can't test.

Comment: @Tetsujin That will only copy the settings between computers. When you do a backup it will copy the settings from each device, but when you restore, it will set to the same device. There's no way to choose which settings to set to which device. Thank you for your input.